# Como obtener ubicación en tiempo real en una aplicación de C# (sin usar un mapa, solo obteniendo latitud y longitud actual)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, geolocalización

estoy necesitando obtener la ubicación de la pc con la que se accede a la aplicación mediante un botón, pero no necesito que me muestre el mapa y busque yo el lugar especificado, si no, que sea de forma automatica, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Vos queres obtener la ubicacion de una pc. en una app de escritorio?

Comment: Mira, hay un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72674/geocoordinatewatcher-no-funciona-correctamente-en-windows-10 Pero ten en cuenta que al ser una PC es muy probable que no tengas datos de posición disponible.

Comment: si, exactamente eso quiero en una app de escritorio, y seria obtener datos de ubicación siempre y cuando se encuentren disponibles, revisare el enlace muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase  [GeoCoordinate Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?view=netframework-4.5)

[GeoLocation .NET 4 and up- requested WinForms example](http://irisclasson.com/2015/09/21/geolocation-net-4-and-up-requested-winforms-example/)

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

watcher.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    var coordinate = e.Position.Location;
    Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}", coordinate.Latitude,
        coordinate.Longitude);

    watcher.Stop(); 
};

watcher.Start();
```

pero vlaida sino tienes que habilitar en windows para que te proporcione el dato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, justo venia a actualizar la pregunta ya que pude encontrar la solucion, y es justo la que me acabas de comentar, solo verificare eso que tengo que habilitar