# como obtener la laitud, longitud, velocidad y direccion con el geolocation que ofrece windows, en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Buenas tardes quiero obtener estos de mi dispositivo
Atributo          Tipo de dato     Descripción
coords.latitude   double           Latitud en grados decimales
coords.longitude  double           Longitud en grados decimales
coords.altitude   double o null    Altitud en metros
coords.heading    double o null    Orientación en grados decimales en el sentido 
                                   de las agujas del reloj
coords.speed      double o null    Velocidad en metros/segundo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi solo me dan laitud, longitud, altitud, mas no la velocidad y orientación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi esta una parte de mi código, help me please.

Comment: que tipo de desarrollo se trata, es una UWP o Xamarin ?

Comment: No creo que una api de geolocalizacion te de la velocidad, porque entiendo se deberia poder calcular en base a la distancia de dos o mas medidas en base al tiempo, a donde apunto es que se trata de un calculo, tienes que tener la distancia y el tiempo para poder calcular la velocidad

Comment: @LeandroTuttini esta app es para conectar un punto from-to (desde- hasta), aquí se llega a tener la distancia de un punto a otro, la velocidad debería ser dada por la api ya que el dispositivo estará en movimiento. Es algo como con pokemon go, cuando tu movimiento excedía una determinada velocidad ya no te contaban como si estarías caminando.en pocas palabras si debería botar una velocidad...
La dirección al parecer me toman el sentido de la vía, algo que debo trabajar con el área de mapas >.< , esta mas tedioso de lo que esperaba... >.<

Comment: o sea la app se usa desde un celular ? usas Xamarin

Comment: @LeandroTuttini explicame tu respuesta de aqui por favor.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214028/como-obtener-ubicaci%C3%B3n-en-tiempo-real-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-de-c-sin-usar-un-mapa/214122#214122

Answer (score 0):

Quizas debas unir la gelocalizacion con la funcionalidad de `Accelerometer`

[Xamarin.Essentials: Accelerometer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/accelerometer)

entonces cuando detectas movimiento en el acelerometro vas tomando muestras con el GPS para tener las coordenadas que puedas reflejar en un mapa o registrar el movimiento.
A medida que se mueva vas podrias ir tomando la geo location

Tambien podrias evaluar el sensor de orientacion

[Xamarin.Essentials: OrientationSensor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/orientation-sensor?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms)

para ver si consigues en que direccion se mueve

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation
aqui te dejo el link, es en UWP.

Comment: los pregunte dos veces y nunca aclaraste si es UWP o Xamarin, a veces ayuda si pones el tag, pero tampoco lo indicaste